# Is HomeKit allow to set two Admin for the same accessory in HomeKit?

Tags: ios, homekit, ios-homekit

I am new in HomeKit development. I have a case/question like
User1 : Create Home (home1),room and add the accessory(accessory1,accessory2) in room. User1 will be now Admin of Home.
User2:Create Home (home2),room. User2 will be now Admin of Home.

Can User2 able to add accessory1 or accessory2 in Home2.

Comment: I have checked for the same in the iOS 9 but it is not allowing two admins for homekit

Answer (score 0):

Not currently. I don't know if there is anything specific in the protocol that restricts the number of admins, but currently the first user to pair with the accessory is the admin, and other users are just added as users.

User1 can invite User2 to home1 so that user2 will have access to the accessories there, but User2 won't be an admin (so can't delete or add new accessories), but user2 would be able to control the accessories (as long as admin only access isn't turned on).

Answer (score 0):

user1 can invite user2 to share the home1 and if user2 want to admin the home1,it need the user1 open the admin to use2.